# Why Bounty reputation not Refunded if there is no answer?

Tags: discussion, support, bounty

I have set bounty on this Question.
[Mangento2 : Use default loader for all process](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/224938/mangento2-use-default-loader-for-all-process)
But I didn't get any helpful answer(even a answer with up-vote).
So I lost 50 reputation without any help

Comment: once i deleted question after bounty period is over, i got +50 bounty points back.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento bounties allows post or question to be visible on the [MSE Homepage featured Tab](https://magento.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured), which I think, can be considered a premium part/feature of MSE.

Regardless of whether your post or question receives an answer or not, the fact that it has been displayed in the **feature Tab** and **got more attention, views and potentially got more chance to get an answer,** I think it is reasonable and fair that your bounty should serve as a payment(in business term) of your post being displayed in the MSE feature page.

Answer (score 6):

From here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/bounty

> All bounties are paid for up front and non-refundable under any circumstances.

Comment: can anyone request for that feature?

Comment: Well @Ketan What happen at that case people start bounty question and end without allocating bounty though they get helpful answer

Comment: According to Doc.If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount (or the full amount, if the answer is also accepted). If two or more eligible answers have the same score (their scores are tied), the oldest answer is chosen. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, no bounty is awarded to anyone.

Comment: @Ketan you are right, but you will never get return your bounty amount in any case